# Is there any way to make these SQL queries faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have a MySQL database and a table with about 128,000 rows (pretty tiny from what I understand).  I also have an application connected to it that is set up to do paging.  My SQL queries look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE PortfolioId = ? LIMIT ?,?
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE PortfolioId = ? ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT ?,?
```

My problem is twofold.  First, regardless of which query is used, the higher the first "LIMIT" number, the slower the query returns, eventually moving into an unacceptable delay.  For instance, if I go to phpmyadmin and execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE PortfolioId = 1 LIMIT 0,20
```

The query takes .001 seconds.  However, when I execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE PortfolioId = 1 LIMIT 120000,20
```

The query takes 14.8 seconds.

My second problem is that the second query where I order by Date (which is also indexed in the table), makes the respective queries take much, much longer (.1 seconds for the first example,  *2 minutes and 23 seconds* for the second example).

Is there a better way to execute these queries so they are much faster? From my understanding, developers often implement paging on tables that have millions of rows but, doing it this way, it would take an extremely long time for the later pages to load.

Comment: If you're doing this for paging, you might consider saving the last returned id from the `Documents` table and using that in subsequent queries. i.e. `SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE PortfolioId = 1 AND DocumentId > ? LIMIT  20`. Note however that this will give different results than your current method if the table is updated between queries.

Comment: The only problem with this is that if I order by different things (like "Date" in my example), the last returned id from the Documents table is going to be useless.

Comment: You can use a similar approach with the date or any other expression you may want to use for ordering.

Comment: @Michael Mior - I will try this.  It would not work as simply as you state, because many documents may have the same date.  Therefore, if I have 100 documents that are all dated July 14, 2012 and my page size is only 20, I cannot simply grab a page that ends on July 14 and on the next page tell it to give me rows with larger dates.  However, if I order by date first and then by id within the date, I should be able to build a query after that (something that limits only to Id > x if the date is the same, and but returns all Ids otherwise).

Comment: @Nerd-Herd - Creating an index for all columns does not help.

Comment: @user1319571 Very good point. I've gotten into a habit of often adding id in the ordering for queries to ensure the order is consistent. As you mentioned something like `WHERE Date >= LAST_DATE AND DocumentId > LAST_ID` should work if you use `ORDER BY Date, DocumentId`.

Comment: @Michael Mior - I have built some new queries using "WHERE (Date = X AND Id > Y) OR (Date > x) ORDER BY Date ASC, Id ASC LIMIT 20", and the speed is much better.  The only issue I have now is that originally the user was going to be able to sort the information by a wide variety of fields, not just the date, in either ascending or descending order.  I may have to disable this functionality for now until I can either come up with an even better solution or figure out how to deal with the complexities that would introduce.

Comment: @Michael Mior - Also, the query you propose in your comment would not work, as a record may have a later date, but a lesser Id, in which case it would not be returned.

Comment: @user1319571 You're right that there are a lot of complexities to deal with here :)

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT will always get slower as your get 'farther' into the result set. Essentially it's not really too much different from fetching the first X rows and throwing them away because you're only interested in X+1 -> X+10. The only difference is that there's no time wasted in sending unwated rows across the wire - MySQL still has to build the entire result set, sort it, then scroll down to whatever your LIMIT offset point is. The deeper your offset, the more work MySQL has to do and then essentially just throw away.

Comment: Ok, if this is the case, then how do developers paging millions of rows make their queries so they do not run into this problem?

Comment: query result caches, so you don't re-execute the whole query every time you change pages, better database designs, 'bigger' databases than mysql, etc...

Comment: Can you elaborate on these techniques so as to provide something useful for my circumstance? I don't see how "better database designs" or "'bigger' databases" would help in this situation, since we are dealing with one table, no joins, and only 128,000 records, but would using some other database greatly speed up LIMIT queries? As for cached query results, do they normally cache the results of the entire table and use that to just return whatever page is needed? Are the results cached within the database, or in the middle layer?